# Unauthorized access API

Tags: c#

I'm trying to access an API via C# but it's giving an UNAUTHORIZED error, I've tried it with the CURL command in CMD it's working, but in C# code it doesn't work, what's wrong:

```cs
try
{
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("GET"), "https://services.efatura.cv/v1/dfe/pdf/CV1220223253095794000010100000000184794720477"))
        {
            request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("accept", "application/xml");
            request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("cv-ef-repository-code", "1");

            request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "Bearer //BearerToken here//");

            var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
            var contents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: are you validating that the headers are successfully added (`Try` normally returns a bool afaik)?

Have you tried looking at the request headers?

Can you see any differences between the cURL and non curl requests?

Comment: I usually just import the curl into Postman, verify it still work, then export that into code https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/generate-code-snippets/

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that your code is exactly the same as your snippet here. In that case you need to actually add a bearer token in the `Authorisation` header.

Usually you can get the bearer token through another GET endpoint with a username and password.
Alternatively you can try to use another form of API authorisation if possible.